# SynthWave '84 theme for VS Code, how to activate glow effect?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded this theme, it was written there "To enable the glow.
As of v0.1.0, external extensions are no longer needed to active the glow.".

I use v0.1.14, so the glowing should start automatically, but it doesn't.
Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, how to do it. After after applying this theme, you should use `Cmd+Shift+P`, after it you can write in search line `Synthwave` and you will see command `Enable neon dreams`.
I hope it will be useful 4U